# How do I delete a Local Publication using T-SQL (by running a query)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, replication

I want to delete the underlined below:

[image]

How do I run a query to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop a publication using [sp_droppublication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188363.aspx).

Comment: sp_droppublication 'REPLICATION_TEST'?

Comment: USE [REPLICATION_TEST]
EXEC sp_droppublication
 @publication = 'REPLICATION_TEST';